# Calculating Vx and Vy given V, X, Y

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have a problem where I am given a trajectory by x(t), y(t) and I am given a constant speed throught the whole trajectory. I need to find vx and vy.

Equations that I am given:

x(t) = 1.5 + 0.5 * t * cos(8*pi*t)

y(t) = 1.5 + 0.5 * t * sin(8*pi*t)

v0 = 0.5

What I have tried to do is use the 1D constant acceleration equations to figure out what the angle of the velocity is:

x(t) = x0 + v0 * cos(alpha) * t

Then I equalized the two x(t) equations:

x0 + v0 * cos(alpha) * t = 1.5 + 0.5 * t * cos (8 * pi * t)

From here, alpha:

alpha = arccos(1.5/(v0*t) + (0.5*cos(8 * pi * t))/v0 - x0/(v0 * t)

I am assuming that x0 in the equation is a given point calculated by my initial x(t) equation

I have tried to calculate the angle with MATLAB:

```
t = 0:0.001:1;
x0 = 1.5 + 0.5 .* t.* cos(8 .* pi .* t);
y0 = 1.5 + 0.5 .* t.* sin(8 .* pi .* t);
v0 = 0.5;


for n = 1:size(t, 2)
    alpha(n) = acos(1.5/(v0*t(n)) + 0.5 * cos(8*pi*t(n))/v0 - x0(n)/(v0*t(n)));  

end
```

From here I am calculating:

vx = v0 * cos(alpha)

vy = v0 * sin(alpha)

And vx is always 0, vy is always 0.5 and that is because all I get for the angle is 90 degrees at all times.
I am assuming that either the way I calculate it within the loop is wrong, or my approach to the equations themselves is wrong, but I can't figure out exactly where my problem is.

Comment: To get $v_{x,y}$ you can just take the time derivative of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Actually I wonder how is meant by " I am given a constant speed throught the whole trajectory." If the $t$-derivative is taken, it turns out time-dependent, it is not constant at all since if $r=(x,y)$: $r =r_0 +v_0 \cdot t \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} \cos(8\pi t) \\  \sin(8\pi t) \end{array} \right)$ will always have dependence on $t$ due to the t-dependent argument of the trigonometric functions and additional terms generated by the chain rule.

Comment: The idea is that v0 will not change through the whole motion, what will change is the ratio between vx and vy but it should always be equal to the desired speed v = sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2) should always be equal to the set velocity. That is why I am trying to find what is the angle of the velocity vector through the motion and then use that to calculate vx and vy for each moment in time.